# How to make a text clickable ONLY WITH JS

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, onclick, click

I don't have any ways to access to the HTML element in my web page, so how can make a clickable link ?
List of code i can't use:
all things like: getElementById
all things that concern DOM

I though about:
`window.open( URL, name, Specs )` BUT i don't know how to make the link between this function and a text generated by javascript...

In fact here's my situation:
I have a function like this

```
blablabla.setNotification("There is my text")
```

and i want some word of my text act like hypertextlink

blablabla.setNotification("There is my text, and there is my **dog**, and just here there is my **cat**")

(cat and dog represent the clickable link)

Comment: Well what is `setNotification`?? Answer really depends on what it does.

Comment: setNotification is a function from Microsoft CRM Dynamics it permit to display a little message next to a field in a form

Comment: Clickable elements are part of the DOM. You can't do anything with them unless you access the DOM. Is there a reason you can't use any DOM methods like getElementById or document.querySelectorAll or something?

Comment: Okay so what does it end up rendering? Does it only allow text or can it be HTML?

Comment: It's deprecated to use DOM in Dynamics CRM so I don't use it :/

Comment: Here's an lookup on the effect of setNotification:
[link](http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-78cY9hx3dn4/VYXZyNTmdGI/AAAAAAAASbs/PzaV2yU3G60/s1600-h/image%25255B24%25255D.png)
and Here's is a lookup on the doc of setNotification:
[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/clientapi/reference/controls/setnotification)